# python numpy: ascontiguousarray use case?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm aware that `ascontiguousarray` returns a contiguous array in memory, but can someone tell me when will it be really necessary? i.e. result is wrong without this function? or perhaps this will make following operations more efficient?

I wrote a convolution function, where I used `as_strided` to change its shape and strides, then `einsum` to multiply with kernel, finally a `moveaxis` so the final shape is (N,C,H,W) as in pytorch. So in this case, do you think I should use an `ascontiguousarray` before the output? Thanks!

Comment: Some special compiled functions assume/require a contiguous data-buffer.  They will raise an error if necessary.  Some `views` are not contiguous.  But usually you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: In this SciPy Japan talk the speaker is saying a bit about contiguous arrays and their performance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYugp9IN1-Q&t=1503s